# How to generate a latin square for a user study?

Tags: experiment-design, latin-square

I have to do a user study for a paper to see how using or not using tool X affects the quality of something (defined in my study). The study goes like this: participant 1 uses tool X to do task A and then a survey after. Then participant 1 does not use tool X to do task B then a survey after. Participant 2 does not use tool X to do task B then a survey after. Then participant 2 uses tool X to do task A. We're looking for around 50 participants.

In summary:

Conditions: use tool X and not use tool X

Tasks: Task A and Task B

Task A and Task B must be done with either using tool X or not using tool X. But both tasks must be done using either mode (use tool X or not use tool X). I'm trying to ensure that the study is counterbalanced such that if my data indicates something that correlates using tool X with task B, it won't be because most participants used tool X for task B before not using tool X for task A. Again the order of using tool X then not using tool X matters. Likewise, the order of performing task A then task B matters. I hope I'm making sense.

I read around that a Latin-square generator is ideal for avoiding order effects but I'm still trying to figure out the right configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems off-topic. How to implement Latin Square in software.

Comment: Thanks, @BruceET. I asked in academia.StackExchange and it also seemed off-topic there. I thought stats.StackExchange would be appropriate. If not where do you think, would be appropriate? Also, do you think the Latin square be done manually? Sorry for the questions.

Comment: If you phrase this as a specific programming problem then it might be on-topic on Stack Overflow. There is also a "software recommendations" stack if you want to ask for a program with specific features.

Comment: There is votes to close, because this is framed as a question about softwares, which is off-tpoic here. But it seems more as a design question, can you please reformulate more as such, for that, you need to give more context&details. Why do you think there is an order effect, are the same participants asked for more than one task?

Comment: Maybe you need a crossover design, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_study .  Maybe add the tag [tag:crossover-study]